# Get android versionCode in ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

How can i get the android:versionCode from my App which I defined in the Manifest.xml with the NDK within C++ ?
I need it to check if the versionCode are newer than X and delete old XML files.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.alexgun.testd"
      android:versionCode="3" <------------------------------------
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

best regards Alex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <cutils/properties.h>

// ...

int myfunction() {
    char sdk_ver_str[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX] = "0";
    property_get("ro.build.version.sdk", sdk_ver_str, "0");
    sdk_ver = atoi(sdk_ver_str);
    // ...   
}
```

Comment: wow thanks for the fast answer. but you get me wrong i  need the <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.alexgun.test"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="1.0"> frome the Manifest

Comment: Android SDK version is not what I need.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, easily at least. You might need to read apk file and go through files to read it. Instead just have config.h, and everytime you change in java part, do the same in config.h

Comment: answer is not related to the question